# ActiveRecord LEFT OUTER JOIN with clauses on left table and grouping by min on the first one

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have two tables similar to first two below in PostgreSQL. `routes` table is just list of available routes to travel with some extra data for filtering. `offers` table have multiple prices for the routes (price depends on the type).

```
offers

 id |  route_id | type  | price
----+-----------+-------+------
  1 |       853 | type5 | 444
  2 |       853 | type1 | 333
  3 |       854 | type1 | 555
  4 |       854 | type2 | 111
  5 |       857 | type2 | 999
  6 |       858 | type3 | 888


routes

 id |   name       | destination_id | car_type
----+--------------+----------------+----------
  6 | Ea magnia    |              1 | car1
  7 | Omnis qe     |              1 | car2
  8 | Ut faci      |              2 | car2
853 | Ut aspe      |              3 | car1
854 | Fugiat atibu |              1 | car2
```

And simple models similar to those:

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :offers
end

class Route < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :offer
end
```

The expected result table may look like this:

```
Expected result

 id | route_id | type  | price |   name       | destination_id | car_type
----+----------+-------+-------+--------------+----------------+----------
  2 |      853 | type1 |  333  | Ut aspe      |              3 | car1
  4 |      854 | type2 |  111  | Fugiat atibu |              1 | car2
```

So, basically, I need to get list of offers with minimum price for every route + information about routes. I have no idea how to to this using ActiveRecord.

I can do something like `Offer.joins(:route).where("routes.destination_id = 1").group(:route_id).minimum(:price)`, but it does not what I expect. + I need to run different `where` clauses on `offers`.

Is it possible to get such results, so that later I can use resulting `offers` objects like `offers.first.type`, or `offers.first.route.name` to access properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom inner join in this case. Something like:

```
bestOffers = Offer.all.joins("inner join (select route_id, min(price) as mini from offers group by route_id) as b on b.route_id=offers.route_id and b.mini=offers.price").includes(:route)
```

This way you can access the offers and routes as you asked.

Let us know if this helps

Comment: This is good answer and does exactly what I need. And adding filters like `...joins(:route).where('routes.destination_id = 1)` also works, so thanks!